# Node.js Version Conflict

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I was using hapi.js and everything was working ok. Suddenly I am getting the following error which I think it is due to node.js version:

```
/Users/jamshidnafisi/Documents/bizbuzz/node_modules/hapi/lib/index.js:5    
const Server = require('./server');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Comment: Where is this line of code?

Comment: @thefourtheye it is in hapi.js library

Comment: *"which I think it is due to node.js version:"* What makes you think that? If you think it is related to the version then you should probably tell us which version you are using.

Comment: Which version of Node.js do you use? If you feel that hapi.js is not backward compatible, you might want to raise a bug in their repository

Comment: @thefourtheye i tried changing the version of node to see how it works. problem is that it was working ok and i dont know what did i do that it stopped working.

Comment: @FelixKling when i change the node version, this error goes away and another one kicks in.

Comment: Till now you have not mentioned the actual versions of Node.js you have tried this on and the version in which the problem is reproducible.

Comment: @thefourtheye currently I am using 0.12.7

Comment: @user3311522 `const` is not supported in v0.12.7 as it uses a very old v8 engine. Please check with hapi.js guys if their library is backward compatible (which I don't think it is), or you might want to choose a version which is compatible with v0.12.7

Comment: @thefourtheye which version would you try?

Comment: Use of `const` in strict mode is available in newer version of nodejs

Comment: @user3311522 The latest, v5.0.0

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that they recently moved some dependencies in the later releases of hapi, for instance to serve static files you now need to import the inert module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hapi v10.0.0 and newer requires node.js v4.0.0 or later. You are using an older version (v0.12.7). Update your node.js version either to v4 or v5 and it will work. You can download node.js here: https://nodejs.org/en/.